# How to create multiple pie charts based on data in DataTable - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, charts

My modification of an old web program in my company is hitting a bit of a snag. Basically its function is to create multiple pie charts based on the data in a DataTable.

Previously the SQL statement and pie chart generation are joined together in a For loop resulting in slow loading times (40 charts = 30+ seconds).

So the first thing I did was separate the SQL statement from the For loop.

```
    Dim query1 As String = String.Format("SELECT DISTINCT A.MacID FROM dbo.tblMachine A LEFT JOIN  dbo.tblDataHdr b on a.MacID = b.MacID where DayID between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND '" & TextBox3.Text & "' ORDER BY A.MACID")
    Dim dt1 As DataTable = GetData(query1)

    Dim result As String = dt1.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) x("MacId").ToString()).Aggregate(Function(a, b) String.Concat(a & "'" & "," & "'" & b))

    Dim query As String = String.Format("SELECT Z.MacID, Z.EventName, ISNULL(DIFF,0) AS DIFF FROM (select distinct MacID, EventName from dbo.tblMachine a " _
                                            & "join (SELECT DISTINCT EVENTNAME FROM dbo.tblEvtDur where EventName <> 'ON'  ) b on b.EventName <> ''  and MacID in ('" & result & "') ) Z " _
                                            & "LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.MacID, A.EventName, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) as diff,round(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) / cast(aVG(Tdiff) " _
                                            & "as decimal(30,8)),4) * 100 AS PER FROM dbo.tblEvtDur  A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MacID, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, STARTdt, eNDdt)) as Tdiff FROM  dbo.tblEvtDur " _
                                            & "WHERE DayID between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'  GROUP BY MacID ) B ON  A.MacID = B.MacID WHERE DayID " _
                                            & "between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'  AND A.MacID in ('" & result & "') group by A.MacID, A.EventName) a " _
                                            & "ON A.EVENTNAME = Z.EVENTNAME  and Z.MacID  = a.MacID order by Z.MacID, Z.EventName")
    Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(query)
```

The DataTable `dt` will be used in creating the pie charts. To give an example of how the data looks here is a sample:

```
----------------------------
| MacID | EventName | DIFF |  'DIFF is total time recorded in seconds
----------------------------
|  A01  |    BLK    |  65  |
|  A01  |    COM    |  0   |
|  A01  |    MDL    |  0   |
|  A01  |    MTL    |  0   |
|  A01  |    OFF    |  0   |
|  A01  |    RPR    |  0   |
|  A01  |    RUN    |  0   |
|  Z09  |    BLK    |  0   |
|  Z09  |    COM    |  0   |
|  Z09  |    MDL    |  0   |
|  Z09  |    MTL    | 256  |
|  Z09  |    OFF    | 3220 |
|  Z09  |    RPR    | 1164 |
|  Z09  |    RUN    | 19874|
----------------------------
```

Each machine has 7 different `EventName` and the time under each event is recorded. Now I need to create a pie chart, one for each machine which covers 7 `EventName`.

However when I move the SQL out of the For loop the pie chart generates wierdly. Here is the code for generating pie chart, under the same sub.

```
Dim check2
PlaceHolder1.Dispose()
PlaceHolder2.Dispose()

For a As Integer = 0 To dt1.Rows.Count - 1

        check2 = dt1.Rows(a)(0).ToString()

        Dim mychart As Chart = New Chart
        Dim ChartArea1 As ChartArea = New ChartArea
        Dim Legend1 As Legend = New Legend

        Dim x As String() = New String(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        Dim y As Integer() = New Integer(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

            x(i) = dt.Rows(i)(1).ToString()
            y(i) = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(i)(2))
        Next

        mychart.Width = 600
        mychart.Height = 400

        mychart.ChartAreas.Clear()
        mychart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1")

        mychart.Series.Clear()
        mychart.Series.Add(0)
        mychart.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(x, y)

        mychart.Titles.Clear()
        mychart.Titles.Add("[" & a + 1 & "] " & check2.ToString.ToUpper)
        mychart.Titles(0).Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 12, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
        mychart.Titles(0).BackColor = Color.PaleTurquoise
        mychart.Titles(0).ForeColor = Color.Black

        mychart.Series(0).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
        mychart.Series(0).LegendText = "#VALX"
        mychart.Series(0)("BarLabelStyle") = "Center"
        mychart.Series(0)("pointWidth") = "1"
        mychart.Series(0).BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid
        mychart.Series(0).BorderWidth = 2
        mychart.Series(0).Label = "#PERCENT"
        mychart.Series(0).ShadowColor = Color.Gray
        mychart.Series(0).ShadowOffset = 10

        mychart.Series(0).LabelBackColor = Drawing.Color.Cornsilk
        mychart.Series(0).Font = New Font("Tahoma", 9, FontStyle.Bold)

        mychart.Series(0).LegendToolTip = "#VALX - #PERCENT"
        mychart.Series(0).ToolTip = "#VALX - #PERCENT"

        mychart.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").Area3DStyle.Enable3D = True

        mychart.Series(0).CustomProperties = "DrawingStyle=LightToDark"
        'new
        Chart1.Series(0).CustomProperties = "PieLabelStyle=Outside"

        mychart.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").BorderDashStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
        mychart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None
        mychart.Series(0).BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid
        mychart.Series(0).BorderWidth = 2
        mychart.Series(0).BorderColor = Color.Black

        mychart.PaletteCustomColors = {Drawing.Color.Black, Drawing.Color.White, Drawing.Color.Blue, Drawing.Color.Yellow, Drawing.Color.Red, Drawing.Color.Orange, Drawing.Color.Green}

        mychart.Legends.Clear()
        mychart.Legends.Add(0)
        mychart.Legends(0).Font = New Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
        mychart.Legends(0).Docking = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Docking.Bottom

        mychart.DataBind()

        If (a + 1) Mod 2 <> 0 Then

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(mychart)

        End If

        If (a + 1) Mod 2 = 0 Then

            PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(mychart)

        End If

    Next
```

All I get is all pie charts having too many quadrants (as in more than 40 slices in a pie chart) and are the same for all machines. Any idea on what to change for my pie chart code?

Comment: This isn't related to your question, but it should be pointed out: you've got a serious security condition in your T-SQL, causing it to be vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. I suggest you do a little research on the problem; named parameters is the solution. FYI Entity Framework will do this for you transparently. You might consider switching to that or some other ORM that uses named parameters internally. As a bonus, you'll find it a lot easier—and will produce significantly more reliable and bug-free code—than you will wrestling with the 'magic strings' inherent in inline T-SQL.

Comment: The SQL is not perfect I admit, but this program is gonna be used within my company only, so I'm not too concerned over any attacks. Besides I want to focus on the pie chart first, once that's done, maybe I'll come back to the SQL again.

Comment: That's how bad habits start ;-)